# I need to make 'ul' by center (with Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I want to make the list centered with the given width.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(26, 40, 114);
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 7px 7px 10px black;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 200px;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center
}

#list {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="text-center">MENU</h1>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="list">
      <li><a href="#">text_1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">text_2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">text_3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">text_4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">text_5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You want the nav center on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options is to change the default behaviour of the ul element and render it as a table. Add this css to #list selector:

```
display: table;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Result:

```css
body {
        background-color: rgb(26, 40, 114);
    }

    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 7px 7px 10px black;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 7px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #menu {
        text-align: center
    }

    #list {
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      display:table;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center">MENU</h1>
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">text_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply give `display: flex;` and `justify-content:center;` to the id `#menu`

```css
body {
            background-color: rgb(26, 40, 114);
        }

        h1 {
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 7px 7px 10px black;
            text-align:center;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 2px solid white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 7px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #menu {
            display:flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #list {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
    <body>
    <h1 class="text-center">MENU</h1>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="list">
            <li><a href="#">text_1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text_2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text_3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text_4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text_5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this one rule:

```
#list li {
  margin: auto;
}
```

And, by the way, it seems you forgot to add this:

```
.text-center {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```css
   body {
        background-color: rgb(26, 40, 114);
    }

    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 7px 7px 10px black;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 7px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #menu {
        text-align: center
    }

    #list {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /*added:*/
    #list li {
      margin: auto;
    }
    
     .text-center {
     width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<h1 class="text-center">MENU</h1>
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">text_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text_5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```